# :after float none not working and trying to find something else

Tags: html, css, class, selector

I'm trying to use the class selector and the pseudo element `:after` and giving that a `float:none;` but it doesn't work.

Anyone had a subsitute?

Comment: Give your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Clearfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  after your code and after that in your `CSS` give `.clear {clear: both;}`